# Count unique words in table with JS

Tags: jquery, count, unique, words

I would like to calculate unique words count in a table with jQuery or maybe SQL. I have no clue at the moment how to do this. So please forgive me when i dont give you my tries.

This is the table:

```
<table>
<tr class="odd">
    <td>450€ Job</td>
    <td>Aachen</td>
</tr>
<tr class="even">
    <td>500€ Job</td>
    <td>Berlin</td>
</tr>
<tr class="even">
    <td>500€ Job</td>
    <td>Berlin</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I would like to get somthing like this:

```
Aachen (1)
Berlin (2)
```

Do you have any ideas? Thank you very much!

Best regards

Comment: How about `Job`? Not counting that?

Comment: Which part is giving you trouble? Finding the words? Counting them?

Comment: You should implement Karp Rabin string matching algorithm

Comment: What does this have to do with `sql`?!

Comment: Just stick the words in an object as keys, and if they are already there, update the value (as in `{word:count}`), and for case-insensitive just use toLowerCase()

Comment: I would like to COUNT unique words in table rows. I have trouble in finding jquery CODE for this. :)

Comment: you got a vote to close from me because even though you say you don't know where to start, the fact you mix jQuery and SQL of all things demonstrates to me that you dont even have cursory knowledge of what you're doing.

Comment: In sql use distinct keyword for finding respective unique names.In jquery get all data and try something like set using sets.Try to use sets data structure of underscore.js

Comment: @Darko Z: the reason i mix jquery and sql is that my table is generated from a database. So i can do it with jquery OR sql. I dont care how and are thankful for any advice.

Comment: Jeezes -> http://jsfiddle.net/xW6r3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here how I would do it using JavaScript. This code calculates words for whole table. If you need to run it for the row, you should modify it appropriately.

```
var words = [];
var uniqueWords = [];

$("td").each(function(){ words.push($(this).text()) });

$(words).each(function(){

    for(var i = 0; i < uniqueWords.length; i++){
        var current = uniqueWords[i];
        if(current.word.toString() == this.toString()){
            current.count++;
            return;
        }
    }

    uniqueWords.push({count: 1, word: this});
});

$(uniqueWords).each(function(){
    console.log(this.count + " " + this.word);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4LSgC/ (see console)

Comment: Thank you very much! With that i can continue my work! :) Superb!