# Count strings in a HTML Table

Tags: jquery

**deleted**

Look at answers for a solution to subject...

Comment: looks like homework. Surely the textbook explained it.

Comment: You've got 3 apples, 1 orange and 2 bananas. Is this a homework question? If it is, you should mention that in the question so you get hints, not code solutions.

Comment: Actually it's not a homework. I'm working on a more complex table of lesson schedule and I need to know how many lesson teachers are doing.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Count unique words in table with JS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20467276/count-unique-words-in-table-with-js)

Comment: Regex probably the way to go. Not sure there is a need for jQuery

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
var apple = $('td:contains("Apple")').length;
var orange = $('td:contains("Orange")').length;
var banana = $('td:contains("Banana")').length;
```